# What are the limitations of using an older ubuntu distribution when a new one is released?

Tags: 12.10

Date: 6 Jan 2015

I have started using Ubuntu 12.10 and the latest version available is Ubuntu 14.04.

I use a USB modem. I get the commands to be executed for it to be used on 12.10 distribution,from ubuntu community. Would I be able to get similar support from Ubuntu community, if I switch to the latest version ?

I am not able to install any new software on 12.10 version and the downloaded .deb file is showing a lot of errors to get installed.

*I am trying to install chrome browser.The error I see is like: dependency is not satisfiable : libboost-iostream1.46.1(>=1.46.1-1)
And I am suggested by the community to install package managers like aptitude or synaptic(to which I see some other errors).*

Would such problems experienced in installing new softwares reduce, if I switch to the latest version ? Would the ubuntu community be helpful to me ?

Comment: Note, questions about version 12.10 are off-topic in this site, as that version has reached its [end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life). Any problems you have with this version cannot be discussed here. On the other hand, if you install 12.04 LTS (Long term Support) or 14.04 LTS or 14.10 (ends after July 2015), you will be able to install security and other updates, and new software with ease. And someone here may help you if you get into trouble.

Comment: Procedural questions like this are not off-topic as such but have been beaten dead already. A duplicate discussion is bound to be around.

Comment: @Rinzwind I should have been clearer. I wanted to say, "One limitation about using an older version like 12.10 is that questions about it is off topic in this site, as that version has reached its end of life."

Comment: Thanks to all the people who have tried to help me. I am going to download Ubuntu 14.04 anyhow !

Comment: I have updated the 14.04(the updates were of about 500 MB) and all the softwares are working fast. The first tip to be given to any new Ubuntu user is to install the latest distro available, otherwise one would have to come to askubuntu again and again. Thanks and Regards to all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ubuntu 12.10 is not supported anymore and as such, third party software like Google Chrome might stop to work. Best is to just upgrade to the latest supported version (like 14.04) if you are able to.

From my experience, the community support is also generally better with later releases since over time more and more users switch to those newer versions. Community support will (to some degree) always be there, but is not guaranteed for all software or hardware.